# what's the real added value in REST routes?

Tags: rest, api-design

AFAIU, RESTful API use http nomenclature to organize API.
From an exemple taken [best practices](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#restful) you'll end up with:

```
http://api.college.com/students/3248234/courses/physics
```

What's the real advantage, from more naïve approach such as:

```
http://api.college.com/course_show?STUDENTID=3248234&COURSETYPE=physics
http://api.college.com/ratings_show?STUDENTID=3248234&COURSETYPE=physics
```

From my view point, first uri mixes stuffs: objects (students, courses) and their params (id for students, type for course). I fell it's a mess.
Moreover, we don't really know what's shown. It is the course taken by this student ? Or the rating our student achieved ? We can suspect that ratings would have been added at the end like .../courses/physics/ratings, but we can't be sure, since the last word is a parameters, not an object.

Second approach is more object oriented, like Course.show(**kwargs), and anyway has the advantage to separate function (or call it method) and parameters (or call it arguments).

Additional point, with this semantic, you can do CRUD but can be more detailed in your interface, like /course_delete or /course_suspend or /course_postpone

So two questions:
1- what's the *real* advantage of REST nomenclature on web API routing ? Isn't just hype ?
2- from security viewpoint, in my exemples, I suspect first url is less secure than second (flask had a problem with that if I remember well), is it correct ?

Comment: If you just look at the three lines, you can easily see that the first one is easier to read (i.e. more user friendly). So that's a 0-1 score already right off the bat :). The answer to your second question is NO. How can a differently formatted URL pose any security risk whatsoever? If any framework has a security issue, then it is a bug in that framework and bugs can happen in anything.

Comment: @RacilHilan I can think of a few different ways that different URIs can have security implications, eg [the IDN homograph attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack). More relevantly, suppose the ratings were supposed to be anonymous. Then both of these URLs would have security risks compared to `http://api.college.com/current_student/courses/physics/ratings`: you need to program in the validation logic that `STUDENTID` matches the logged-in student’s ID, instead of not having any endpoint for getting ratings you don’t have access to.

Comment: Your question really seems to be about superficial URL parameter conventions, not about REST. What you imply is a REST format is certainly more regular and predictable; and you could obvoiously use a longer label if you need to distinguish between, say, `courses_offered_by` and `courses_taken_by` or you think your users won't otherwise know e.g. from reading the API documentation. Coversely, the legacy CGI-like format could just as easily have `x23=456` instead of a human-readable label as far as the computer is concerned or the architecture dictates.

Comment: @DanielH Just to clarify, in my first comment I said "differently formatted URL", which means that the URLs carry the exact same info, only formatted differently. Your comments were all about removing some data from the URL. That's not a "differently formatted URL", it's a completely different URL, and yes that off course has an impact on security. I fully agree, but that's not really related to the question.

Comment: @RacilHilan, yes by security I though the way frameworks parse routing. Setting your route with parameters in it could lead to security issues if framework is not rock solid in its handling. Parsing url get/post parameters usually is common enough to be well-handled. It was my question. Sure every framework has bugs, but new features/methods are more bug-prone/less audited.

Comment: If you're comparing features, not URL formats, then yes, new features are more prone to errors. However, the route feature is not new. Yes, it is more recent than the parameters in query string, but it's already been around for many years now.

Comment: @RacilHilan, bug on flask I was thinking of is this one ( https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/37814/ ), fact is that it appears with route-style uri pattern. (but it's true that it could have appeared with cgi-pattern)

Comment: That exploit was in 2015 and we're almost in 2018 now. But most importantly, that exploit seems to be related to the debugger being accidently enabled in production. That's a human error, not a framework bug. Enabling debuggers in production is a big issue for any framework (although framework should help prevent it). In all cases, this exploit doesn't seem to have anything to do with the route-style URI pattern, they just happened to use it in their example, but they could've used the CGI-style and probably achieved the exact same results.

Comment: @RacilHilan I missed some of your comments when looking at the thread again, that makes sense. I deleted my redundant comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what's the real advantage of REST nomenclature on web API routing ? Isn't just hype ?

[REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) doesn't care what spelling you use for your identifiers.

[URI Templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) are a convenient way to generalize identifiers for different resources; this convenience is most frequently seen in mapping resource identifiers to implementations in the server, but are also sometimes seen as a means to describe a family of identifiers to a client that understands [hypermedia representations](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3).

Judicious use of [path segments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) when describing a hierarchy of resources, allows you to take advantage of the client's ability to [resolve relative references](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5).

> from security viewpoint, in my exemples, I suspect first url is less secure than second (flask had a problem with that if I remember well), is it correct ?

No? Neither of them offers any security at all; they are just identifiers.

Comment: Identifiers can have security implications. If I saw the third example, `http://api.college.com/ratings_show?STUDENTID=3248234&COURSETYPE=physics`, and I wanted to know how my friend rated the physics course, I would consider plugging in their student ID. If the URL didn’t have a place for student ID at all, but assumed the currently-logged-in student, then nobody on the back end would need to code the student ID validation logic.

Comment: Maybe also mention that "split on slashes" is a lot simpler than the parsing required for a CGI-style URL. Even an intern in the suburbs of Seattle can implement the former (though they are now launching a new and improved *Idiot(r) 365(tm)* which does percent escapes before splitting on slashes).